# Inputting data into separate index array using preg_match php

Tags: php, arrays, preg-match

I'm trying to go through an array with integers and store the matches in different indexes of the array that increments by 1. At the moment it is just being stored in one index which is zero.

Here is my code:

```
for($results = 0;$results<$length_g;$results++){

if(preg_match('/[0-9]+$/', $game_scores[$results], $away_goals)){

$away_goals[results];

}
}
```

Comment: What is your problem? Sorry I don't get it.

Comment: I want to store the data in a different index of the array "$away_goals". So it will add an extra element to the array

Comment: Maybe add your inputs and outputs and desired result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're not assigning a new value. Try this:

```
$new_array[$results] = $away_goals;
```

Then you could use `$new_array` to get the data afterwards.

Comment: Good way of doing it. I was thinking of array_push

Comment: I like the **KISS**-principle ;) http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/KISS_principle

Answer (score 0):

array_push does this. But have to create a new array to store the data in.

Code:

```
$away_goals = array();

for($results = 0;$results<$length_g;$results++){

if(preg_match('/[0-9]+$/', $game_scores[$results], $away_score)){

//echo "Match was found <br />";
array_push($away_goals, $away_score);

}

}
```